# firefox issue xmlhttprequest through GET method

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

This `javascript` code works on google chrome but for some strange reason it fails to work on firefox:

```
var username=document.querySelectorAll(".x-births .l-p4 weak")[0].innerHTML; 
if (username!="") 
{ 
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/example.php?a=123",true); 
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Basically i run this code on a site and if it succeeds, `example.php` stores a log in `example.html` where i can see if the request is made.
Now when i run that code on google chrome on the same site in the same place, i get the logs, if i run it on firefox, i do not get anything, why is that happening? Is it a compatibility issue?
It's a very strange problem. Also, yes the username is not equal to nothing in both browsers.
Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Alert and check if you are getting username

Comment: I already did and yes i do get the username.

Comment: also put alert inside if condition and check if it goes